# Bootstrap datetimepicker style not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm trying to use bootstrap-datetimepicker but I can't make it show properly.
I followed the installation part of the tutorial.

**Screenshot**

My result :

[image: style not applied]

The example from the doc :

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group date">
        <label class="input-group-addon" for="add-event-start"><span class=
        "glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></label><input class=
        "form-control" id="add-event-start" name="start" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#add-event-start').datetimepicker({
    allowInputToggle: true,
    locale: 'fr',
    icons: {
        time: "fa fa-clock-o",
        date: "fa fa-calendar",
        up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
        down: "fa fa-arrow-down",
    },
});
```

**Head**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fullcalendar.min.css">
<link rel="stylehseet" href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3-respond-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

**Body**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/validator.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/moment/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/moment/fr.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/fullcalendar/fr.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

I tried to remove some includes to prevent conflicts but i had the same result.
Can someone tell what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you create a Fiddle or such to help us identify the problem faster.

Comment: Which tutorial are you following?

Comment: The one from the doc : http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/

Comment: I don't exactly know what's wrong, because you don't explain what's supposed to be seen, but it seems to me everything is aligned to the left?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get the same results as your picture when I neglect to include or disable  the Bootstrap Datepicker CSS stylesheet. (Step 6 of the [guide](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/)):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />
```

In your sample code the tag seems to be present in your header, but you must make sure it's loaded as well. Maybe the path or the file itself is wrong.

Comment: It's well included, I checked ... I also tried with the style from the doc !

Comment: It's almost impossible to get exactly the same results by other faults than this one. If you're really sure the right file is included and loaded properly, I wonder if it has the correct content.

Answer (score 0):

I get *exactly* the same thing! :(

However, if you use the versions of bootstrap-datetimepicker.css and bootstrap-datetimepicker.js from the demo site it works.

The versions on the demo site are 4.15.35 and not the latest 4.17.37 available from GitHub...